# Mark exported classes in Eclipse to not modify

Tags: eclipse, class, export, readonly

in my workpsace i do have SVN checkout classes and SVN export classes.
I seperate the classes into two working sets. The exported classes are members of another feature based project and i am not allowed to change this classes inside my workspace.

When i want to fix a bug or implement new features i want to be sure, that the exported classes are not touched.

Can i mark exported classes with a flag, that i can not modify this classes in my workspace. Something like read only would help. Does somebody knows a similar problem with an existing solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I can think of that might help here.

1. Mark everything as read-only in the file system. If you edit in eclipse, it will prompt you if you try to edit it, asking if you want to make it read/write.
2. Mark everything as derived. Same type of prompting will occur, warning you it's a derived file. The problem here is that unless you have a plugin that can mark things as derived, you'll need to mark every file. (Writing such a plugin is very easy though - if you want to take this approach, email me: scott@javadude.com)

Neither of these will completely stop you, but the prompting might help (and if you do both you'll get two prompts...)

Hope this helps!